# convert .gif image from an url to .png

Tags: iphone

how to convert .gif image from an url to .png ?, i have a url containing .gif images. Do simulator support .gif image?

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [dic objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

get image in NSData format

use

```
[UIImage imageWithData:dataObject];
```

and convert it into UIImage format then conver it in png format
by using this line

```
 NSData *dataForPNGFile = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourJpegImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulator does support .gif image, but if you are using animated gif, you are not going to get any animation and the image will look weird.